# How to select multipe files for vimdif using netrw?

Tags: netrw, vimdiff

Suppose I have some files in a folder. I browse the folder using vim `vim myfolder`. It opens `netrw` with a list of the files in the directory. Now I want to select two or more files and then open them in comparison mode. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation...`:help vimdiff`? The answer is right at the beginning...`:help start-vimdiff`

Comment: @BLayer Did you read my question? I saw nothing in the begining, it speaks about command line like `vimdiff file1 file2`, but I'm speaking about exploring the files and then opening them side by side. My main problem is that the filenames are long and I someway need to select them in browser window.

Comment: Your question is actually hard to understand. There are hundred ways to open two files in vertical splits. But there's no such thing as "vim browser". If you mean netrw then you should read `:h netrw`. If it's another plugin then read its documentation and so on. Next, you were adviced to read `:h vimdiff` but it looks you never got after first few lines. At least, do the first section until the end before complaining that someone haven't answered your question.

Comment: Open the files as usual in whatever window layout you need. Once you have all files you'd like to diff open, use `:windo :diffthis`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I don't know the first part actually, how I open two files in vim by selecting their name... (not using command line)

Comment: @Matt Thanks, My question isn't much difficult. As I wrote type `vim myfolder` (not file)... what you see? without any plugin it lists the files (I called it browser), I don't know what is it called? Now my problem is how to **select** and open two files? I know that `v` opens a file in a splitter window beside the browser, now I need another key to switch to the browser window and select the second file....That could be a common case and huge help of vim isn't straightforward for it. So, I think a website like this could provide a short answer

Comment: @Matt okay thanks, I myself found the short answer I sought for.

Answer (score 3):

When you opened the folder using vim, `vim thefolder`

- navigate to each file using arrow keys and press `mf`, it marks the files,
- then press `md`, it calls vimdiff on the selected files (up
  to 3 files).

There are other commands in this mode, use `:h netrw` to find more